# How do I convert a data buffer in JavaScript into a file?

Tags: javascript, file, xmlhttprequest, buffer, binary-data

I am receiving a data buffer from an node/express endpoint on my client side and I want to convert the buffer into a file.

The file may be a pdf, text document, or image. The only information the endpoint tells me is that it's sending an octet stream.

How do I go about doing this?

This is the code I have so far on my client side

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "MY_URL", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

// I need to send some data for the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

// send request
xhr.send(`identifier=${myIdentifier}`);

xhr.onload = function (xEvent)
{
    const arrayBuffer = xhr.response;
    if (arrayBuffer)
    {
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray]));

        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf"); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }
};
```

Comment: are you getting type of the file or is there any possibility to get file type?

Comment: @VishnuShenoy Thank you for replying. The endpoint on my server actually gets the data from an external private endpoint and forwards it to my client. I'm mostly sure the private endpoint sends file type, but I don't know how to get the file type from the response and send it to my client. On the private endpoint the file downloads and opens correctly.

Comment: i have done this but it need file type then only it will work.... wait ill share you the code

Comment: I'm still looking for help on this.

Answer (score 5):

convert arraybuffer to base64 and then to url, generate fileUrl for view

```
arrayBufferToBase64(Arraybuffer, Filetype, fileName) {
        let binary = '';
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(Arraybuffer);
        const len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        const file = window.btoa(binary);
        const mimType = Filetype === 'pdf' ? 'application/pdf' : Filetype === 'xlsx' ? 'application/xlsx' :
          Filetype === 'pptx' ? 'application/pptx' : Filetype === 'csv' ? 'application/csv' : Filetype === 'docx' ? 'application/docx' :
            Filetype === 'jpg' ? 'application/jpg' : Filetype === 'png' ? 'application/png' : '';
        const url = `data:${mimType};base64,` + file;
    
        // url for the file
        this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    
        // download the file
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = fileName;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
```

Comment: I tried to use this but when the file downloads, my local PDF reader shows `File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported`. I am only working with PDF files right now. Also, what is `this` in your answer?

Comment: this is a public variable been accessed.. declare it on top as public fileUrl: any;
if ur working only with pdf then use declare Filetype = pdf before calling fucntion

Comment: Yes, I did set the type as pdf. It just doesn't seem to work. I am just setting up a basic ad hoc proxy service for protected binary streams. Not really sure how I can do this. Thank you for sharing though!

Comment: @StackMatch Did you find a solution for this?    I have the same problem.

Comment: I have shared the answer, pls chk the answer section